# LINQ operation creating cast exception

Tags: excel, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

While reading data from data-table which is populated by from an excel file, getting "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'." exception when column datatype is double. My code looks like below

```
 var importedProducts = dtImportedData.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(dtProduct => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtProduct.Field<string>("product_id")))
                        .Select(dtProduct => new
                        {
                            product_id = dtProduct.Field<string>("product_id").Trim(),                              
                            product_qty = Convert.ToInt32(dtProduct.Field<double>("product_qty "))
                        }).ToList();
```

When product_id column has text datatype, all is OK. But when there is double datatype, it is throwing exception.

I have already tried solution from [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1924400.aspx?Unable%20to%20cast%20object%20of%20type%20System%20Double%20to%20type%20System%20String%20in%20LINQ)

Comment: So you have a column that change its type magically to another type?

Comment: @Steve, You are right. User change excel column datatype as per his wish and we cannot control it.

Comment: Logically then you shouldn't use the same code to read different datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if `product_id` is a double and not a string, why you cast it to `string` at all?

```
.Where(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Field<double>("product_id").ToString()))
.Select(row => new
 {
    product_id = row.Field<double>("product_id"),                              
    product_qty = (int)row.Field<double>("product_qty")
 })
```

I don't like the `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` approach with a field that contains a `double` or `double?`. I'm pretty sure that you could use (to be tested):

```
.Where(row => row.Field<double?>("product_id").HasValue)
.Select(row => new
 {
   product_id = row.Field<double?>("product_id").Value,                              
   product_qty = (int)row.Field<double>("product_qty")
 })
```

If you don't know the type of a `DataColumn` in a `DataTable` you can execute this in the debugger:

```
dtImportedData.Columns["product_id"].DataType;
```

This is what you have to use in `Field<T>`.

---

If the type is really changing as commented this is the safest:

```
.Where(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row["product_id"].ToString()))
.Select(row => new
 {
    product_id = row["product_id"].ToString().Trim(),                              
    product_qty = int.Parse(row["product_qty"].ToString().Trim())
 })
```

Comment: Tim Schmelter, product_id datatype is string. But I am populating dtImportedData variable from an excel file and user keeps on changing excel column datatype.

Comment: @user1926138: i don't understand, is it string or double or changing, what is it? You have seen my tip at the end of the answer?

Comment: Its changing. User can use any datatype in excel sheet and I need to convert it to string.

Comment: @user1926138: added another approach